# What is the right way to import this python file?

Tags: python

I have the current directory structure:

```
- api
  |
   - app.py
  |
   - tests
     |
      - test_app.py
```

What is the correct way to import `app.py` into `test_app.py`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: Is it possible for you to change your directory structure? You can check [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/) to see what is the desired project structure.

Comment: That's an interesting article @alparslanmimaroğlu. I managed to solve thanks to @OlvinRoght 's link with ```import sys``` and ```sys.path.append('..')```